# MVP. Участвует ли Presenter при клике по списку и переходе в другое View

Tags: android, архитектура, mvp

Разбираюсь в архитектуре MVP. Пока НЕ использую никаких Dagger'ов, RxJava и т.п., просто пытаюсь перевести несложное приложение c MVC на MVP.

Если происходит событие - "клик по кнопке 'добавить' " в некой форме, то тогда дергается Presenter,... он сигналит в Model, ... там происходит добавление, и он потом дергает у View обновление/изменение экрана с какими-то новыми данными. Здесь вроде понятно.

**Вопрос:**
 если происходит событие во *View - "клик по списку" каких-то сущностей и открывается новый фрагмент с выбранной сущностью, т.е. (никакого изменения данных не происходит) по сути переход от одной View в другую,
учаcтвует ли здесь слой Presenter?

У меня возникли сомнения в том моменте, когда сущность -(данные), по которой произошел клик передается с одного View в другое так:

View -> View

или
через Presenter это  надо делать? Т.е. передать в Presenter кликнутые data, а потом он должен передать это в другую View?

View -> Presenter -> View

Спасибо!

***View - в данном вопросе, исключительно, как составляющая MVP, а не android.view.View**

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, паттерн MVP очень широкий, и какого-то определенного канона нет. Каждый использует по разному. Самый просто пример MVP следующий.

1. View - например это у нас активность
   В ней мы пишем :

   Presenter presenter = new Presenter(data);
2. Presenter - некий класс, в котором отправляется запрос или делаются какие-то действия, если отправляется запрос, то запрос получает некую Model, с которой мы в дальнейшем работаем.
   Так вот. Отправили запрос, получили ответ, некую модель. Далее мы вызываем метод нашей view,куда передаем данную модель(данные), в этом методе view отображает эти данные.

3.Model - это некий класс, в котором описана структура ответа сервера, POJO.

Вот как-то так это и работат.

P.S
У тебя может возникнуть вопрос относительно того: "Эм, а в чем отличие MVP от MVC"? Основное отличие в использовании такой либы как DataBinding позволяющая привязывать модель к каким-то вьюхам.

Comment: Спасибо за фидбэк! Я понимаю различие MVC от MVP, чем занимается Presenter, Model и View в общих чертах мне понятно, а вот в моем конкретном case непонятненько

Comment: В вашем кейсе, передаете данные через view -> view
Обычно через bandle или intent
Использование презентара - избыточно)

Comment: @StanlyT выше написал)